# OS.File in Firefox SDK Add-on

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

This is my first attempt at writing a Firefox add-on.

I'm trying to read a text file that is contained in an Firefox Add-on I'm writing.

I'm following the example [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_OS.File/OS.File_for_workers#Example.3A_Reading_the_contents_of_a_file_as_text)

```
let decoder = new TextDecoder();      // This decoder can be reused for several reads
let array = OS.File.read("file.txt"); // Read the complete file as an array
let text = decoder.decode(array);     // Convert this array to a text
```

In my `main.js` I have the following snippet of code :

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/osfile.jsm");

var pathFile = OS.Path.join("_locales", "en", "messages.json");        

let decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');

let promise = OS.File.read(pathFile);        
promise = promise.then(
  function onSuccess(array) {
    return decoder.decode(array);
  },
  function onReject(array) {
    console.log("onReject read: ");
  }            
);
```

When I run the add-on using the `cfx run` command, I get the following error:

```
Message: ReferenceError: TextDecoder is not defined
```

I'm currently using Firefox 30, and the Firefox Add-on SDK 1.16.

Should I not use `OS.File` in `main.js` in an add-on?

Should I use `FileUtils` instead, i.e. `Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you linked the `OS.File` for Workers-docs. You don't use it in a worker (no `new Worker` anywhere), but the main thread, so you'll instead want to refer to [`OS.File` for the main thread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_OS.File/OS.File_for_the_main_thread)-docs.

SDK modules unfortunately don't get `TextEncoder`/`TextDecoder` automatically right now.
As @erikvold suggests, you could:

```
const { Buffer, TextEncoder, TextDecoder } = require('sdk/io/buffer');
```

or even get it from `osfile.jsm` directly:

```
const { Cc, Ci, Cu } = require("chrome");
const { OS, TextEncoder, TextDecoder } = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/osfile.jsm", {});
```

Now back to your original question:

In general `OS.File` can be used in SDK add-ons and is a good way to read/write arbitrary file in the file system.

However `OS.File`, `FileUtils`, `sdk/io/...` are not suited for reading files in your add-on, because usually those files won't be located directly in the user's file system, but instead be located within the installed XPI file (which is merely a zip file) and these APIs allow you to read files verbatim, but don't parse the container zip files (XPI) for you.

You have a couple of options, though:

- The file name seems to indicate that **you want to localize something**. The SDK comes with the [**`l10n` module**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/l10n) exactly for this purpose.
- Stuff located in the `data/` folder of your add-on can also be read with [`self.data.load()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/self#data.load%28name%29), but you still need to decode/parse the data.
- You can read files packaged in your add-on (XPI) with [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), which the SDK makes available in the [`net/xhr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/net_xhr) module. As an added bonus, you can have the `XHR` object decode and/or parse the file for you by setting an appropriate `.responseType` value.

Constructing the URI for `XHR` is easy if the file to read is located in the `data/` folder of your add-on, e.g.

```
cont self = require("sdk/self");
var uri = self.data.url("en/messages.json");
// would map to data/en/messages.json
```

Otherwise, there isn't really an official, supported way to get URIs, but e.g. the following will work for `lib/` (at the moment, but might fail in the future).

```
cont self = require("sdk/self");
var uri = self.data.url("../lib/main.js");
// would map to data/../lib/main.js -> lib/main.js
```

Placing your own files somewhere else is tricky, as the SDK will only package certain paths when building the XPI; in general `lib/`, `data/`, `locale/` (see `l10n`), `chrome/` (see [XUL Migration Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/XUL_Migration_Guide))

Here is a minimal example using `XHR` (but remember that for localization there is the `l10n` module already):

```
const self = require("sdk/self");
const { XMLHttpRequest } = require("sdk/net/xhr");

// Assume data/some.json is:
// {"abc":123}
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onload = function() {
  // req.response is an object containing the parsed JSON.
  console.log(req.response.abc); // 123
};
req.open("GET", self.data.url("some.json"));
req.responseType = "json";
req.send();
```

PS: When working with `OS.File` in particular and promises in general, consider using [`Task.jsm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Task.jsm) which can make it much easier to write and re-read (maintain) code.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.  I was able to read in the data from the file using the XHR approach.

Comment: Another option is to set in your `install.rdf` the `<em:unpack>true</em:unpack>` and then use os.file no?

Comment: @Noitidart Don't use `<em:unpack>` if you don't absolutely have to. There are performance reasons `<em:unpack>` was implemented and defaulted to `true`...

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
const { Buffer, TextEncoder, TextDecoder } = require('sdk/io/buffer');
const { OS } = require("resource://gre/modules/osfile.jsm");

var pathFile = OS.Path.join("_locales", "en", "messages.json");        

let decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');

let promise = OS.File.read(pathFile);        
promise = promise.then(function onSuccess(array) {
  return decoder.decode(array);
}, function onReject(array) {
  console.log("onReject read: ");
});
```

Comment: Honest question: Did you SDK folks implement support for JSM in `require()` or is this an oversight in your example?

Comment: @nmaier I don't know the technical details, but it does seem to work. I just tested it in an extension I am working on and was able to use `require` to import both `osfile.jsm` and `FileUtils.jsm`